# AWS:Device Name Error when converting from Elastic Beanstalk instance from m3.xlarge to m4.xlarge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Elastic Beanstalk application using an *m3.xlarge* EC2 instance.

I wanted to try out using *m4.xlarge* instead so I cloned my EB instance. Then once it was running I clicked on *Change Configuration* and changed the *Instance Type* to *m4.xlarge* but then this gives the following error

```
Invalid root device name: '/dev/sda1', expecting: '/dev/xvda'.
```

Why is this error occurring ?

I have found this article

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html

which gives some background information but I still dont know what to about this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the problem was an *ebextension* script, did not realize they were checked at that stage, but I had configured a larger root disk, and in there it referred to /dev/sda1

```
Resources:
    AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration:
        Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
        Properties:
            BlockDeviceMappings:
               - DeviceName: /dev/sda1
                 Ebs:
                     VolumeSize:
                        35
```

changing it accordingly fixed the issue:

```
Resources:
    AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration:
        Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
        Properties:
            BlockDeviceMappings:
               - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
                 Ebs:
                     VolumeSize:
                        35
```